# Controlling UITableView Headers changing opacity in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When my table view loads it's headers are translucent, but if I scroll it off screen and bring it back, it is opaque.

Initially I wanted them to be opaque, but I'm not sure now so I'd like a solution for either scenario. Changing `isOpaque` to `false` (the default) has the same behaviour.

My delegate method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.tintColor = .headerColor
    view.isOpaque = true
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = .white
}
```